# WatchKit page control position

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Is there a way to move the default page control that shows up on a page-based WatchKit app? The interface is created in a storyboard, I didn't find a way to add the control separately, nor any way to access the default one.

[image: Result]

[image: Storyboard configuration]

Comment: I don't think that is possible, you can't even recolor it.  There is very limited scope for customisation with WatchKit controls as Apple wants to keep the UI consistent between Apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this thing.The default implementation is given in the documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/2143142-reloadrootcontrollers. 
Moving it anywhere other than the bottom will not be the right indicator that its a page based layout that Apple follows across its watch applications. 
Is there any specific functionality you want to achieve by moving the page indicators?

Comment: Hey Chander, thanks for your input! I was just trying to match a design I received, where the page indicator dots were higher ‍♂️